# Initialize enum by string in c (keil v5)uvision

Tags: c, arrays, enums, keil

I'm using these code to receive string from uart then matching them with this enum then putting them on switch-case.

```
char temp[3],rx_buf[100];
enum form {
GGA = 1,
GSA
};
enum form gnssform ;

sprintf(temp,"%c%c%c",rx_buf[3],rx_buf[4],rx_buf[5]);
gnssform=temp;
```

I can't understand that we can directly use something like EXAMPLE:

```
gnssform=GSA;
```

and there is no error ,but this:

```
gnssform=temp;
```

not compiling .and please tell me the possible way to do this???,because of this EXAMPLE I believe that it must be possible. 
the error is :

### a value of type "char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "enum form"

please do not tell me to use if-else because I hate that.

Finally I used

```
if(rx_buf[3]=='G'&&rx_buf[4]=='G'&&rx_buf[5]=='A')gnssform=GGA; 
else if(rx_buf[3]=='G'&&rx_buf[4]=='S'&&rx_buf[5]=='A')gnssform=GSA;
```

Comment: *please do not tell me to use if-else because I hate that.* - Use `if-else`, or quit programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GSA` is a constant value of `enum form`.

`temp` is a char pointer to the three letters 'GSA'.

They are not the same thing, and you cannot directly assign them.

Comment: there is no way to convert?? :'(

Comment: With an 'if-else' block.  Well, you could get fancy and copy your 3 bytes into an int32_t, then do a switch and then assign, but that's just doing work to make things complicated.

Comment: `int32_t myInt = ((rx_buf[3]<<16) | (rx_buf[4]<<8) | rx_buf[5]))`, then do a `switch` on `myInt`, with the `case` statements like `case (('G'<<16)|('S'<<8)|('A'):`

Comment: but how directly detect `gnssform=GSA;`

Comment: Finally:
`if(rx_buf[3]=='G'&&rx_buf[4]=='G'&&rx_buf[5]=='A')gnssform=GGA;

else if(rx_buf[3]=='G'&&rx_buf[4]=='S'&&rx_buf[5]=='A')gnssform=GSA;`

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in solution. Easiest way is with an array of char* where the enum's int value indexes to a string containing the descriptive name of that enum.

```
enum FRUIT_ENUM {
    apple, orange, grape, banana,
};

static const char *FRUIT_STRING[] = {
    "apple", "orange", "grape", "banana",
};
```

Then you can do something like below in a loop.

```
if (!strcmp(FRUIT_STRING[n],temp)) 
gnssform=n;
```

Comment: Hi! I can't understand the second part , the problem is that `gnssform` can not be assigned as `string`. :'(

Comment: sorry it is gnssform = n;